# Logging and tracing on Azure

Tags: azure

We are looking a solution for logging and tracing for our multi-tenant application with distributed architecture, that will be hosted on Azure.

We have already gone through these two articles –  [Troubleshooting Best Practices for Developing Windows Azure Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh771389.aspx) and [Enabling Diagnostics in Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/?sec=commontasks). Is there anything other better solution?

We would like to know 
•   what are the best practices and approach for it? 
o   Storage strategy?
•   Any third party / open source tool that helps us for the same?

EDIT:
We are looking for two things:

1. Best practice for storage strategy, where should we store log data? Since it's multi-tenant multi-tier application, should we keep data separate for each tier per tenant, combine them or any better solution? How do we store the data so that we can trace single request individually that spanned across multiple tiers?
2. A tool that helps us to view trace data, analyse them, filter, sort, etc. Since size of trace data will be comparatively huge, trace a flow of single task that spanned across multiple tiers.

I have used System.Diagnostic with XML listener, in on-premise application - with multiple tiers (web app, service layer 1, service layer 2, etc). I then, used Microsoft Service Trace Viewer to view the log data. SVCTraceViewer supports many features including combining log files of many tier, graphical representation, tracing individual request, etc.

So, some thing similar third party / open source tool for Azure.  That also helps support engineer to drill down the issue and resolve it.

Comment: Is there something that windows azure diagnostics does not do for you? Why are you looking for something else?

Comment: Hi Mike, I have updated my query, that helps to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking into an open source library like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).  It provides a pluggable/fully configurable and super flexible way to log messages with a lot of custom data and to a lot of sources.  Configuration for it can be retrieved from external sources/xml, code, config files, etc.

You can create your own appender for Table Storage or find someone [else's](http://cloudshaper.wordpress.com/2010/10/30/logging-with-log4net-on-the-azure-platform/)

HTH

Comment: For non Azure projects I totally agree about log4net, but I think it is less powerful on Azure because of its dependency on the application web config, even in the table appended in your link.

Comment: You can drive its configuration from an XML file stored externally in a URL.  Custom table storage appender can read the connection information from Service config.

Comment: Yes, I can use log4net. But what about viewer? (I have updated my question)

Comment: Since you'd be storing a custom schema in the table storage to help differentiate it between your tenants, you'd need to roll up your own viewer (should be nearly trivial to do considering lack of complexity) or use default table-storage viewers that are built into Visual Studio, or perhaps one from Cerebrata Storage Explorer, etc.